# Vuetify combobox set focus to the next combobox when yes is clicked on a dialog

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify combox control in a project I also have a dialog that pops up @blur to the next combobox to confirm the entry that is typed in the first combobox I am have two issues going on.

the first issue is that I want to set focus onto the next combobox or input when yes is clicked on the dialog I have tried using nextTick for this with some code to make it focus but it does not work. How can I go about setting this up so that it focuses the next input when yes is clicked ?

The second issue is that when you click on the next combobox the dialog gets its name from the item that is clicked. So if I were to type something into category then click on the next combobox manufacturer would show up in the dialog instead of category.

Can anyone point me to some insight on how I can correct this ?

I have setup an example in code sandbox for you to take a look to see if yall can help me out on these issues.

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-galileo-ycxw8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Rather late than never.

You can set the `autofocus` prop to have it focused.

```
<v-combobox
  :autofocus="focusCombox"
  ...
```

Check their API: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/